# Modify All Permission for an Object- Insufficient Privilege

Tags: permission-sets

I have created a permission set . It involves 3 object . 
Object Contract is in a Master detail relationship with Account and Agreement.

I need to create and SAVE Contract records.
With all other permissions remaining same , when I remove Modify ALL permission from Agreement Object , I get Insufficient Privilege Error .

How do I find the root cause ?

Comment: With the M:D relationships how are the permissions on the detail records defined - Read/Write or Read only? Are the agreements owned by different uses from the Accounts?

Comment: @DaveHumm- Read/Write: Allows users with at least Read/Write access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records. Yes , the Account which is being selected was created by a different user .

Comment: @DaveHumm-I have tried with Agreements and Account created by same user as well as different user . both give the error when Modify All is revoked.

Comment: If it fits with the business requirements then change the Read/Write access to Read only.

Comment: @DaveHumm- And what about the  Agreement/Account same user you mentioned ?